# Jekyll date off by one

Tags: jekyll

I recently added a post to my Jekyll blog, and noticed that the date was off by one.

Instead of

```
http://www.tianxiangxiong.com/2016/09/24/dont-be-a-hacker.html
```

I ended up with

```
http://www.tianxiangxiong.com/2016/09/25/2016-09-24-dont-be-a-hacker.html
```

It's curently around 10:30 PM in California (5:30 AM UTC). Is this a time zone problem? If so, why does Jekyll care about any date aside from the one I specify in the file name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the post is actually broken due to the quotes in your front matter:

```
excerpt: "Hacking" is not a satisfactory way of writing software
```

Should be:

```
excerpt: '"Hacking" is not a satisfactory way of writing software'
```

The timezone issue could be some sort of unintentional follow on behaviour from that, since the title and permalink are also messed up.

---

In any case, you could always set your timezone in `_config.yml`.

```
timezone: America/New_York
```

From https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/:

> **Time Zone**
>
> Set the time zone for site generation. This sets the `TZ` environment variable, which Ruby uses to handle time and date creation and manipulation. Any entry from the [IANA Time Zone Database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) is valid, e.g. `America/New_York`. A list of all available values can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). The default is the local time zone, as set by your operating system.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. I was not aware of the quoting rules w/ YAML (we should all use [edn](https://github.com/edn-format/edn) instead!).